# File Upload component not working with TLS

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have been using Primefaces 2.2.1 file upload component, but it seems that it doesn't work with SSL or TLS - HTTP ERROR. I have been trying RichFaces File Upload component, but I dont Know if it is even possibile to integrate it with Primefaces. Is there any other JSF component I can use with SSL? It is going to be fixed in next Primefaces relase?
When I'm following [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/02/uploading-files-with-jsf.html) I'm just getting

```
<partial-response>
<changes>
<update id="javax.faces.ViewState">
<![CDATA[ -4529855290807263768:-3315128550281964003 ]]>
</update>
<extension primefacesCallbackParam="validationFailed">{"validationFailed":false}</extension>
</changes>
</partial-response>
```

as response. Submit method is not triggering.

Comment: The highest PF version that works with my app is 3.0.2M. File upload works (But not in wizard component). Hope stable version will fix all the problems.

Comment: Do you mean SSL rather than SLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a real problem for Primefaces 2...

Now, if you use the new Primefaces 3.0.M4 you will be surprised with the results: uploading files with TLS works just fine (tested), and no more flash for us. I hate flash!

I know that the current version it's just a beta one but it's somehow far better that Primefaces 2, and there are only a few days to wait until RC1 release.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadHome.jsf

Comment: I would just say, that you are right. This component uses Flash which just doesn't go very well with SLL - it seems to be unaware of that.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem, although I used primefaces upload componenet.
I fixed it bij removing enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</h:form>

<h:form>
...
</h:form>
```

then I didn't get any more validation errors, hope it helps...